# Playing an animation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, fltk

Just want to put delay of few microsec so I can see my animations. Delay function is not working. I am using fltk so anything with that also can help.

```
for(i = 0; i < 1; i = i + 0.1)
{ 
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(i,i,1);
    glRotatef(spin, 0, 0, 1);
    delay(1000);
    glScalef(i,i,i);
    glutWireCube(1);        
}
```

Comment: what happens is my animation is drawn all together.What I want is it should draw one then delay and then draw the other.

Answer (score 4):

You don't play animations that way in OpenGL (well technically you could put a SwapBuffers at the end of the loop, but that's not a good idea).

What you should do is implementing an idle handler, that issues a redraw when called. In the drawing function you should time the time between calls to the display function to advance the animation by that amount.

*Never(!)* run a loop in which you add a sleep or similar. Such code is not responsive to outside events, and modern OS will consider programs behaving like that as nonresponsive/hung and show the user a message box that allows for killing the program. This is not what you want.

Comment: can you post an example for this.

Comment: So you basically want your code written for you, @user1733735

Comment: @user1733735: Writing some example code would require to know which runtime environment you have. How do you create your OpenGL context? Which frameworks do you use? What is the overall structure of your program.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2010. I have used FLTK, opengl I have this code in my draw() function.